# Importance Sampling for Least Square Monte Carlo

Tags: option-pricing, r, monte-carlo, american-options

I am currently trying to implement and model an Importance Sampling estimator for Longstaff and Schwartz algorithm for pricing American put options. It is used such that more paths are in-the-money such that less simulation is required and also the variance is reduced.

I am following the steps by [Moreni](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/free-version/doc/premia-doc/pdf_html/Moreni_doc.pdf) and simulate $n$-paths of a drifted geometric brownian motion given by:

$dS_t = S_t\big[(r+\theta \sigma)dt+\sigma dW_t\big]$.

Then moreni defines the likelihood ratio $L_\tau^\theta=exp\{-\theta W_t+0.5 \theta^2 t \}$.

By the stopping time theorem, we want to find for each path $n$ $\sup_\tau \mathbb{E}[f^{(n)}(\tau,S_\tau)]$ the corresponding Importance sampling estimator $\sup_\tau \mathbb{E}[L_\tau^\theta f^{(n)}(\tau,S_\tau)]$, where $f$ is the payoff function.

When we have found the stopping time for each path $n$ we can take the average and get the desired put price at time 0.

My question is that is the wiener process in the likelihood ratio the random number at $\textit{optimal}$ time $\tau$ for path some path $n_i$? And at the same time should $t$ be the optimal time $\tau$ for path $n_i$?

Since in R the standard L&S algorithm is existent in the package `library(LSMonteCarlo)`, i modified the function `AmerPutLSM`, such that it simulate with drift $\theta$ and i set the interest rate to 0.
However, I seem to get very high prices when I try to simulate compared to the standard one. So I am not sure if I really have understood the math correctly. I use negative values for $\theta$ and it should be around -0.5 and -1 according to Moreni. But the prices I get are really deviating.

Here is the code, that I modified:

```
firstValueRow <- function (x)
{
  cumSumMat <- matrix(NA, nrow = dim(x)[1], ncol = dim(x)[2])
  for (i in 1:(dim(x)[1])) {
    cumSumMat[i, ] <- cumsum(x[i, ])
  }
  cumSumMat2 <- cbind(matrix(0, nrow = dim(x)[1], ncol = 1), cumSumMat[, -(dim(x)[2])])
  ResultMat <- matrix(NA, nrow = dim(x)[1], ncol = dim(x)[2])
  for (i in 1:dim(x)[2]) {
    ResultMat[, i] <- ifelse(cumSumMat2[, i] > 0, 0, x[,i])
  }
  return(ResultMat)
}

Spot = 36
sigma = 0.8
theta = -1
mu = 0
n = 1000
m = 50
Strike = 40
r = 0
dr = 0
mT = 1

dt <- mT/m
GBM <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = m)
Zlist <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = m)
for (i in 1:n)
{
  Z <- rnorm(m, mean = mu, sd = 1)
  GBM[i, ] <- Spot * exp(cumsum(((r+theta*sigma-0.5*sigma*sigma)*dt)+(sigma*(sqrt(dt))*Z)))
  Zlist[i, ] <- Z
}
X <- ifelse(GBM < Strike, GBM, NA) #stock rates only in the money
### payoff importance sampling
Ltheta <- exp(-theta*Zlist-0.5*theta*theta*dt)
CFL <- matrix(Ltheta*pmax(0, Strike - GBM), nrow = n, ncol = m) #cashflows

Xsh <- X[, -m]
X2sh <- Xsh * Xsh

Y1 <- CFL * exp(-1 * r * dt)
Y2 <- cbind((matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = m - 1)), Y1[, m]) #value of derivate at time t+1

CV <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = m - 1) #continuation value
for (i in (m - 1):1)
{
  reg1 <- lm(Y2[, i + 1] ~ Xsh[, i] + X2sh[, i])
  CV[, i] <- (matrix(reg1$coefficients)[1, 1]) + ((matrix(reg1$coefficients)[2,1]) * Xsh[, i]) + ((matrix(reg1$coefficients)[3,1]) * X2sh[, i])
  CV[, i] <- (ifelse(is.na(CV[, i]), 0, CV[, i]))
  Y2[, i] <- ifelse(CFL[, i] > CV[, i], Y1[, i], Y2[, i + 1] * exp(-1 * r * dt))
}
CV <- ifelse(is.na(CV), 0, CV)
CVp <- cbind(CV, (matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 1)))
POF <- ifelse(CVp > CFL, 0, CFL)
FPOF <- firstValueRow(POF)
dFPOF <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = m)
for (i in 1:m)
{
  dFPOF[, i] <- FPOF[, i] * exp(-1 * dt * r * i)
}

PRICE <- mean(rowSums(dFPOF))
PRICE
```

Should the cashflows be multiplied by the likelihood ratio immediately?

Appreciate for help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just made things clearer hoping it would help.

Let define $\mathbb{Q}_\theta$ as $$\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_\theta}{d\mathbb{P}}|_{\mathcal{F}_t}=\exp(\theta W_t -\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t)=Z^\theta_t$$

By girsanov, if $W$ is a brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}$, then $W^\theta_t=W_t-\theta t$ is a brownian motion under $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$

$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[f(\tau, W_\tau)]=& \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}_\theta}[(Z_\tau^\theta)^{-1} f(\tau,W_\tau)] \\
= & \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}_\theta}[e^{-\theta W^\theta_\tau-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2\tau}f(\tau,W^\theta_\tau+\theta\tau)]
\end{split}$$

and if $\tau$ was defined as :

$$\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0 : W_t \in A_t\}$$
then $$\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0 : W^\theta_t+\theta t \in A_t\}$$

defining $\tau^\theta$ as :

$$\tau^\theta= \inf\{ t\geq 0 : W_t+\theta t \in A_t\}$$

you finally get (using your $L$ notation) and the equality in law

$$\mathbb{E}[f(\tau, W_\tau)]=\mathbb{E}[L_{\tau^\theta}^\theta f(\tau^\theta,W_{\tau^\theta}+\theta \tau^\theta)]$$

Comment: So when I simulate from the drifted GBM, am I simulating from $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$ ?

Comment: @Elekko yes and the likelihood ratio is here given by the (inverse of) the Radon-Nikodym derivative. You "just" need to simulate under the changed measure and weigh the exercise value at the optimal stopping time by the likelihood ratio to perform importance sampling.

Comment: @MJ73550 nice answer. However I don't understand the point of introducing $\tau^\theta$ ? Is it purely for notational convenience?

Comment: Well I simulate them by discretizing $dS_t = S_t\big[(r+\theta \sigma)dt + \sigma dW_t \big]$, then get the optimal stopped times and values for each path. However when I weight them, drift of say $\theta = -1$ gives a extremly high values for the option when I mutiply EACH value with its UNIQUE Loglikelihood, that is dependent on $\tau$ and $Z_\tau \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: I think that I get confused by the underlying itself. We have $\mathbb{E}[L_{\tau^\theta}^\theta f(\tau^\theta,W_{\tau^\theta}+\theta \tau^\theta)]$, as MJ73550 mentions. However the PAYOFF function $f$ is a function of $S_t$ (i.e $f(t,S_t)$) and that is dependent on the Wiener process.

Comment: Under $\mathbb{P}$ $dS_t=S_t(rdt+\sigma dW_t)$, then
$S_t=S_0 \exp((r -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t)=S_0 \exp((r+\sigma\theta -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W^\theta_t)$

Comment: Have you tried your importance sampling method for a plain vanilla option?

Comment: There is a good paper from Jerome Lelong and Benjamin Jourdain on the gaussian importance sampling by shifting the mean

Comment: Well pure vanilla such as European put, we only look at the maturity date. However, for the american option case, the payoff function is dependent on the optimal stopping time. Meaning that the "likelihood function" is dependent on the optimal stopping time for each scenario